# How can I skip a field from being translated by react-18n?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have some data I want to translate. Those data are being translated with locize and react-18n into different languages. However, I need some fields to be skipped but they are not. Image url and navigation links are expected to remain unchanged in other languges also but this is not happening.

Example:

```js
"headerNavigation": [
    {
      "link": "/",
      "name": "Home"
    },
    {
      "link": "/about",
      "name": "About"
    },
    {
      "link": "/products-and-services",
      "name": "Products & Services"
    },
    {
      "link": "/buy-commodities",
      "name": "Buy Commodities"
    },
    {
      "link": "/contact",
      "name": "Contact"
    }
  ],
```

Result in German:

```js
"headerNavigation": [
    {
      "link": "/",
      "name": "Heim"
    },
    {
      "link": "/Über",
      "name": "Über"
    },
    {
      "link": "/Produkte und Dienstleistungen",
      "name": "Produkte"
    },
    {
      "link": "/buy-commodities",
      "name": "Rohstoffe kaufen"
    },
    {
      "link": "/Kontakt",
      "name": "Kontakt"
    }
  ],
```

Different corresponding json were generated and based on the route, the right json is being used to serve the content. For instance, if I am on http://localhost:3000/en, it will use the English translation and the German if I am on http://localhost:3000/de

I just need some translation to remain unchanged. For instance, what I am expecting for German translation should be:

```js
"headerNavigation": [
    {
      "link": "/",
      "name": "Heim"
    },
    {
      "link": "/about",
      "name": "Über"
    },
    {
      "link": "/products-and-services",
      "name": "Produkte"
    },
    {
      "link": "/buy-commodities",
      "name": "Rohstoffe kaufen"
    },
    {
      "link": "/contact",
      "name": "Kontakt"
    }
  ],
```

I am mapping through the file with something like: https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

Comment: By fixing your locale JSON to keep the English words?

Comment: Why do you need to add the links to the translation files if they are not changing?